# IIS cannot display pages

Tags: asp.net, iis

After using asp_regiis on Windows server and IIS 8.5, when browsing any page on IIS even localhost, I got:

> page can't be displayed error

### Update

I can browse the server by IP from any other machine in the same network, but still the problem exists internally (in server itself).

Comment: What happens when you browse a sample html page over localhost ??

Comment: same error "this page can't be displayed"

Comment: ok understood. Try this - Reproduce the issue one more time. Open IIS logs C:\inetpub\logs\w3svc_websiteID and check if you see any entry there. If you do, look for the status code and substatus code at the end of the line. 

However, if you do not see any entry in IIS logs, open HTTPERR logs in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR and see if you have any request there and look for the error.